# Spotify audio player stops randomly after few seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, spotify, playback

Sometimes when I play sound file, it stops randomly after few seconds."didChangePlaybackStatus" method of SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate gets called after fews seconds. The issue is not so frequent but can be reproduced after few tries. Need help.

```
- (void)audioStreaming:(SPTAudioStreamingController *)audioStreaming didChangePlaybackStatus:(BOOL)isPlaying {
    _playerController.nowPlaying = self.isPlaying = isPlaying;
}
```

-- Here is the screenshot for the call trace, when audio stops automatically.

[image]

Comment: Please add code as well so others can see what is the problem.

Comment: @C_X Dear I added stack trace, please check if it helps.

Comment: I am having the same issue with SPTAudioStreamingController,  Player stops playing automatically and giving the same stack trace.

Comment: I added break points to below delegate methods, but control is not going through these delegates even.

- didEncounterError;
- audioStreamingDidDisconnect;
- audioStreamingDidEncounterTemporaryConnectionError;

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your are not using same spotify account more than one place.
As in my case I was using my account in two devices (android+ios) and was getting same issue.